# Add a picture to a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, embedded-resource, imageicon

All I am trying to do is add a picture to a `JFrame`.

I am really confused and don't really understand... I have looked up every possible question on this site, looked on other java stuff, such as forums. I tried my best and now I must ask guys for help. I hope the code is clean and easy to read. Thanks for the help.

```
package zeus;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

public class Main extends JFrame{

    public static final int WIDTH = 800;
    public static final int HEIGHT = 600;
    public static final int SCALE = 1;

    public static void Launch(){

        JFrame xF = new JFrame("xFrame");
        xF.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        xF.setResizable(false);
        xF.setVisible(true);
        xF.setSize(WIDTH*SCALE,HEIGHT*SCALE);
        xF.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        xF.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("/Clicker/xS/cow.png")));

    }

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Launch();

    }

}
```

Very sorry for the confusion, eclipse shows no error, also I am trying to open a JFrame with an image on it, that I can eventually use to create into a button to change a value of a int value.

Comment: Can you please let us know what is the error message that you are getting?

Comment: Please describe the difficulty you are having, also please include what it is you are trying to do. As it stands now your question is going to be closed.

Comment: If you have looked up every possible question, surely you know how to make a question yourself.

Comment: BTW - I edited your question to replace the title with a statement of intent - what you are trying to achieve.  Please don't use titles like your original title in future.  I suspect that is in large part why the 8 down-votes were added.  It is just silly.  Another factor might be claiming you have checked *"every possible question"* when.. you obviously haven't.

Comment: Please have a look at this thread, [Load Icon Image Exception](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9866659/1057230), especially the eclipse link and the last link, which might can give you the whole idea, as to how to go about it :-)

Answer (score 3):

The biggest issues I can see are...

- Extending from `JFrame`, but not actually using it...
- Reliance on `static` when not really required...
- Calling `setVisible` before anything has actually begin added.  In fact, generally trying to manipulate the frame properties before anything was added to it and after it was made visible...

  public class Main {

  ```
   public static void main(String[] args){

       EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
           public void run() {

               JFrame xF = new JFrame("xFrame");
               xF.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
               xF.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("/Clicker/xS/cow.png")));
               xF.setResizable(false);
               xF.setSize(WIDTH*SCALE,HEIGHT*SCALE);
               xF.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
               xF.setVisible(true);

            }
       }
   }
  ```

  }

But since you never actually described what problems you were having, these are all guesses...

Comment: All I am trying to do is add a picture to a jframe D:

Comment: `xF.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("/Clicker/xS/cow.png")));`  Is the problem.  Have you not, in your 'extensive' research, encountered the term 'embedded resource'?

Comment: Where is `/Clicker/xS/cow.png` stored?

Answer (score 1):

I have a couple of tips for you:

- If you know your frame size then there is no need to over-complicate it
- Try using frame as the JFrame's name rather than xF so it is easier to look at.
- Rearrange your methods so that setVisible(true); is at the end.

Now, as for your code I suggest you use two classes: One for the frame and one for the panel.

**The frame class**

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Apollo
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    Jframe frame = new JFrame("xFrame");
    frame.setSize(800,600);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setContentPane(new Poseidon());
    frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

**The panel class**

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Poseidon extends JPanel
{
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g.fillRect(0,0,800,600);

    ImageIcon clicker = new ImageIcon("/Clicker/xS/cow.png");
    /*The following are two methods for image sizing,
     *Use the one that best fits your code:
     *
     *g.drawImage(clicker.getImage(), x, y, null); 
     *Fill in the arguments for x and y to locate your upper left corner
     *The image will be in it's original size
     *
     *g.drawImage(clicker.getImage(), x, y, w, h, null);
     *Fill in the arguments for w and h to set the width and height of your image
     *The image will be in it's scaled size
     */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use 
**xF.setContentPane(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image_path)));**